# How many ways to get the change?

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming

While practicing the following dynamic programming question on HackerRank, I got the 'timeout' error. The code run successfully on some test examples, but got 'timeout' errors on others. I'm wondering how can I further improve the code.

The question is

```
Given an amount and the denominations of coins available, determine how many ways change can be made for amount. There is a limitless supply of each coin type.
Example:
n = 3
c = [8, 3, 1, 2]


There are 3 ways to make change for n=3 : {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2}, and {3}.
```

My current code is

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

from functools import lru_cache

#
# Complete the 'getWays' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return a LONG_INTEGER.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER n
#  2. LONG_INTEGER_ARRAY c
#

def getWays(n, c):
    # Write your code here
    #c = sorted(c)
    
    @lru_cache
    def get_ways_recursive(n, cur_idx):
        cur_denom = c[cur_idx]
        n_ways = 0        
        if n == 0: 
            return 1
        if cur_idx == 0:
            return 1 if n % cur_denom == 0 else 0
        
        for k in range(n // cur_denom + 1):
            n_ways += get_ways_recursive(n - k * cur_denom, 
                   cur_idx - 1)
        return n_ways
    
    return get_ways_recursive(n, len(c) - 1)
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

    n = int(first_multiple_input[0])

    m = int(first_multiple_input[1])

    c = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    # Print the number of ways of making change for 'n' units using coins having the values given by 'c'

    ways = getWays(n, c)

    fptr.write(str(ways) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

It timed out on the following test example

```
166 23 # 23 is the number of coins below.
5 37 8 39 33 17 22 32 13 7 10 35 40 2 43 49 46 19 41 1 12 11 28
```

Comment: on the other hand if the cache is indeed working, changing it's size could almost certainly help with the timings, just tested it and using `@lru_cache(1000)` makes the code return immediately

Comment: Here is good video explaining the mechanics of this DP solution - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ4a7cmjZY0